# Calculate speed of a moving object that is far and closer from Camera

Tags: android, physics

I am developing an Android application which can tell the speed of a moving object. I got the speed calculation technique already. But I am facing problem, how to calculate speed of a far or closer object from Camera.

Currently I am using VelocityTracker:
http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement.html#velocity

and using below example:
http://android-er.blogspot.jp/2013/12/velocitytracker-track-velocity-of-touch.html

Then I convert pixel/s to km/h in my calculation.

But for far object, even if the object moves with high speed but it looks moving slower on device screen. Or if the object is very closer, calculation should be different. I am planning to do the Calibration based on this scenario. Do you have any idea how to fix this issue?

Thank You

Comment: What issue? What calculation are you having trouble with?

Comment: Hi ,I need your help I also developing same application can you help me Please @user968677

Comment: Old question, but here is my 2 cents. AFAIK it's not possible to detect depth with android camera alone without "calibrating" it first. Even if you caibrate it, it will not be very accurate at all. That is why range finders use lasers to track dictance. Also, you mention that you are using `VelocityTracker` - this is used to track the speed at which your finger moves on the device. In my experience `VelocityTracker` is not very accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but for people with the same issue :
You will need to estimate the distance d of the object tracked to figure out the speed via triangulation.

Then, if you know the distance D and dimension L of any object in the scene, you can use Thales theorem to figure out the speed :

```
L/D=vT/d
=> v=Ld/DT
```

[Little sum-up scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbl9T.png)